# Unix(AIX): tail: unable to malloc memory Error, when using pipes

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, tail

My requirement is to chop off the header and trailer records from a large file, I'm using a file of size 2.5GB with 1.8 million records. For doing so, I'm executing:

```
head -n $((count-1)) largeFile | tail -n $((count-2)) > outputFile
```

Whenever I select count>=725,000 records (size=1,063,577,322), the prompt is returning an error:

```
tail:unable to malloc memory
```

I assumed that the pipe buffer went full and tried:

```
head -n 1000000 largeFile | tail -n 720000 > outputFile
```

which should also fail since i'm passing count> 725000 to head, but, it generated the output.
Why it is so? As head is generating same amount of data (or more), both commands should fail, but the command is depending on tail count. Is it not the way where, first head writes into pipe and then tail uses pipe as input. If it is not, how parallelism is supported here, since tail works from end which is not known until head completes execution. Please correct me, I've assumed lot of things here.

PS: For the time being I've used grep to remove header and trailer. Also, ulimit on my machine returns:

```
pipe (512 byte) 64 {32 KB}
```

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1):

Just do this instead:

```
awk 'NR>2{print prev} {prev=$0}' largeFile > outputFile
```

it'll only store 1 line in memory at a time so no need to worry about memory issues.

Here's the result:

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR>2{print prev} {prev=$0}'
2
3
4
```

Comment: @Morton, thanks for your suggestion. However, I really want to know why is that failing and why it is depending on tail instead of head.

Comment: I understand but idk why exactly (but it's probably related to buffering) and this will get you past the problem so you can continue development while you wait for an answer to that specific question.

Comment: @ShanthanK You should ask IBM then, but even if they give you an answer, you still have to find some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test this with a large file, but it will avoid a pipe.

```
sed '1d;$d' largeFile > outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Ed Morton and Walter A have already given workable alternatives; I'll take a stab at explaining why the original is failing. It's because of the way `tail` works: `tail` will read from the file (or pipe), starting at the beginning. It stores the last lines seen, and then when it reaches the end of the file, it outputs the stored lines. That means that when you use `tail -n 725000`, it needs to store the last 725,000 lines in memory, so it can print them when it reaches the end of the file. If 725,000 lines (most of a 2.5GB file) won't fit in memory, you get a malloc ("memory allocate") error.

Solution: use a process that doesn't have to buffer most of the file before outputting it, as both Ed and Walter's solutions do. As a bonus, they both trim the first line in the same process.

Comment: If thats the case, then, tail should fail with the file input as well:

   tail -n 1000000 largeFile 

But this is succeeding. Shall I conclude that tail uses buffer only when reading from a pipe?

Comment: I doubt, for pipes it's true, but for files tail reads from the end: "Print the last N_LINES lines from the end of file FD. Go backward through the file, reading 'BUFSIZ' bytes at a time (except probably the first), until we hit the start of the file or have read NUMBER newlines."